# CanCan Auth issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Good Afternoon All,

I am trying to sort out my user authentication and causing myself headaches.

I have a :role_type defined in User and my user has two roles, Employer or Developer, now I my user is currently developer and should be able to see jobs#index but it cannot and I get the default cancan message of unauthorized:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

and here is the Ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    can :create, :delete, :update, Job if user.role_type == "Employer"
    can :read, Job if user.role_type == "Developer"
end
end
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The user has only one role right? And you are expecting a user with `:role_type` "Developer" to be able to access `jobs#index`?
By the way: you have to pass multiple abilities as an Array like this: `can [:create, :delete, :update], Job if user.role_type == "Employer"`

Comment: I hoped that the missing Array was breaking it and hoped that it would work after adding it. another thing I can think of is that your user's role is "developer" instead of "Developer" maybe. Which version of Rails and CanCan are you using?

Comment: I know that rails 4 is having problems with CanCan when using `load_and_authorize_resource`, but only for `create`. The `index` action should work fine and I cannot see why this is not working for you. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comments: Make sure that you are not having a typo like "Employer" instead of "employer" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error occurs when the `user.role_type == 'Employer'`

Looking at your code it looks like the Employer is missing the `:read` action.
If `Employer` can manage all jobs (basic crud actions) you might want to consider giving him the `:manage` ability

Example:

```
can :manage, Job if user.role_type == "Employer"
can :read, Job if user.role_type == "Developer"
```

The :manage ability gives the user access to every action within the JobsController. See the following doc for clarification on the :manage ability:  https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities#the-can-method

Otherwise you would need to add the `:read` action to `Employer`, as they are not a `Developer` and will not get the `:read` action

Comment: My issue is with Developer, not Employer, my current user is logged in as a Developer. I tried changing this and does not work for Developer but it does make more sense to use :manage though so thanks.